# Is there an inverse of the yday lubridate function?

Tags: r, date-arithmetic

I have a list of days in the format "day of the year" obtained by applying lubridate::yday() function to a list of dates. For instance, from the following dates (mm-dd-yyyy format):

```
01-01-2015
01-02-2015
...
```

by applying yday() you get

```
1
2
...
```

Is there a function that can do the reverse given the yday output and the year? Ie, from a yday value and a year, get back to a date in the mm-dd-yyyy format?

Comment: I believe this type of question would be better off at StackOverflow.

Comment: A solution may just be to create a sequence of days (mm-dd-yyyy format), apply the lubridate::yday() function for day and get the year. Then just do a simple merge or join. Don't over think it.

Comment: You do _not_ need a merge.  R has Date arithmetic. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any sequence* added to a `Date()` type creates a new `Date()` sequence with just that offset.

Witness:

```
R> as.Date("2016-01-01") + 0:9
 [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03"
 [4] "2016-01-04" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-06"
 [7] "2016-01-07" "2016-01-08" "2016-01-09"
[10] "2016-01-10"
R> as.Date("2016-01-01") + 100:109
 [1] "2016-04-10" "2016-04-11" "2016-04-12"
 [4] "2016-04-13" "2016-04-14" "2016-04-15"
 [7] "2016-04-16" "2016-04-17" "2016-04-18"
[10] "2016-04-19"
R>
```

So once again a so-called lubridate question as nothing to do with that package but simply requires to know how the base R types function.

Comment: Nice - always like the simple date solutions. Also, `as.Date(paste(100,2015), format="%j %Y")` will work appropriately.

Comment: Interesting.  Had not tried 'yearday year'; makes sense. Had noticed before that 'weeknum year' fails -- not a date as undecided among seven possibilities.  'weekday weeknum year' works.   But reparsing is inferior to just adding :)

Comment: It may be simpler to stick with the lubridate syntax the OP is already familiar with, and use `parse_date_time(..., orders = "j")`

Answer (score 4):

To do this with the **lubridate package**, you use the `parse_date_time()` function with `j` as the `order =`  argument.

Example:

```
my.yday <- "1"
parse_date_time(x = my.yday, orders = "j") 
# [1] "2021-01-01 UTC"
```

The default appears to be the current year. If you want to specify the year just add it in!

```
my.yday <- "1"
parse_date_time(x = paste(1995, my.yday), orders = "yj")
# [1] "1995-01-01 UTC"
```

Note: make sure you supply the julian day as character, not numeric. If numeric it will fail when over 3 digits (weird bug that they don't plan to fix)

Comment: Note: there is currently a bug in the package where if the yday is >= 100, it only parses if it's in character format. Until they fix this, the fix in your code is to supply yday as a character vector instead of a numeric vector.

Answer (score 1):

Just as round out the answer by @DirkEddelbuettel, since I was having the same issue and its been 3 years.

In order to get the desired mm-dd-yyyy for a given dataset where you have only the year  and the calendar day as a result of `lubridate::yday()`.

You just need to offset a `Date()` type object for that given year starting at january 1st, by what your `yday()` output is subtracted by one.

Then if you want to get the month or day within that month you can use lubridate's `month()` and `day()` functions to pull those parts.

(I assume you have the year since that will impact the calendar date b/c of leap years, messing up your month/day assignment. If not, any year will do)

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

#Example dataset with years on/around leap year
my_df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015),
  my_yday = c(150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150)
)


#skip straight back to the yyyy-mm-dd format
my_df %>% mutate(new_date = as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")) + (my_yday - 1))

#Get every component
my_df %>%
  mutate(
    new_day   = lubridate::day(as.Date(str_c(year, "-01-01")) + (my_yday - 1)),
    new_month = lubridate::month(as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")) + (my_yday - 1)),
    new_date  = as.POSIXct(str_c(new_month, new_day, year, sep = "/"), 
                           format = "%m/%d/%y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> yday ("1990-03-17") - 1 + as.Date ("1990-01-01")
[1] "1990-03-17"
```